# Error in HTML when run "ionic cordova build android --prod --release"

Tags: angular, ionic4

I try to run my code but this error come out. What should I do to solve it?

This are the error:

```
ERROR in src\app\part-d\part-d.page.html(24,105): : Property 'customActionSheetOptions' does not exist on type 'PartDPage'.
src\app\part-d\part-d.page.html(75,97): : Property 'customAlertOptions' does not exist on type 'PartDPage'.
src\app\partd-stpm\partd-stpm.page.html(157,141): : Property 'onSelectChange' does not exist on type 'PartdStpmPage'.
src\app\partd-stpm\partd-stpm.page.html(184,62): : Property 'onSelectChange' does not exist on type 'PartdStpmPage'.
src\app\components\multi-file-upload\multi-file-upload.component.html(20,35): : Property 'uploadfile' does not exist on type 'MultiFileUploadComponent'. Did you mean 'uploader'?
src\app\components\multi-file-upload\multi-file-upload.component.html(20,35): : Property 'uploadfile' does not exist on type 'MultiFileUploadComponent'. Did you mean 'uploader'?

[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.
```

Comment: adding your html and ts would help us figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just from the error it looks like you haven't got a 'customActionSheetOptions', 'customAlertOptions' variable in your .ts file for your PartDPage component just add:
.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'select-example',
      templateUrl: 'select-example.html',
      styleUrls: ['./select-example.css'],
    })
    export class SelectExample {

      //this is the missing bit your missing 
       customAlertOptions: any = {
    header: 'Pizza Toppings',
    subHeader: 'Select your toppings',
    message: '$1.00 per topping',
    translucent: true
  };

  customPopoverOptions: any = {
    header: 'Hair Color',
    subHeader: 'Select your hair color',
    message: 'Only select your dominant hair color'
  };

  customActionSheetOptions: any = {
    header: 'Colors',
    subHeader: 'Select your favorite color'
  };
    }
```

the same goes for your other errors you need to add these properties to your .ts files for those components. the typescript sections of the code are present below the html in the docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add all your variables in component file  which are used in template with public as access specifier.

**Any variable as a private specifier, it will not allow to use in template in production mode**